# PHP - Saving checkbox with submit button

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am attempting to build a checklist in which you will be able to select / deselect multiple checkboxes and save them to the page using a submit button.

Below is the code I am working with:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" name="save" id="save" />
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" />Tickets</li>
            <ul>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="person1" id="person1" value="1" />Person 1's ticket</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="person2" id="person2" value="2" checked />Person 2's ticket</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="person3" id="person3" value="2" />Person 3's ticket</li>
                <li><input type="checkbox" name="person4" id="person4" value="2" checked />Person 4's ticket</li>
            </ul>
</form>
```

PHP: [only shown for 1]

```
            <?php
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='person1' id='person1' value='1' checked />";
            } else {
                echo 'There was an error.';
            }
        ?>
```

I cannot seem to get the checkboxes to hold the data after the page is refreshed. 

 

Upon clicking save I would like the page to reload and the checkboxes to hold their data. 


I am trying to keep this quite simple, so the least amount of code, the better. Everything I am able to find requires the use of jQuery or databases.


I am fairly new with PHP and any assistance is greatly appreciated.


**A live version of my site can be seen at www.magycka.us to better understand what this is being used for.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered by creating a mysql database and using PHP to store the values as a 1 or 0 in the db.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Send the data to the PHP. (Give the inputs a `name` and `value`).
2. Write some PHP to pay attention to that (it will be in `$_POST`) and output the `checked` attribute **conditionally**.

If you want the results to persist when the page is loaded afresh, you'll also need to store that data somewhere (like a database) and then retrieve it if the page is loaded via a GET request instead of a POST request).

Comment: This is a bit vague. I have updated my code and documentation based on your answer. Please take another look. I am unsure what to do with the PHP portion. 
As I said PHP is all quite new to me.

Comment: @CodyM — The only time you look at anything in `$_POST` is when you check `$_POST["save"]` … but you have no input named `save`. You never look at `$_POST['person1']` (or 2 or etc). You echo out the whole input, with the `checked` attribute every time. So your condition is checking the wrong thing and isn't restricted to determining if the `checked` attribute will be set or not.

Comment: I updated the save button to have a name of save. 
How would I go about doing something like this? 

Something like:

    <?php
            if (isset($_POST["person1"])) {
                echo "<input type='checkbox' ' value='1' checked />";
            } else {
                echo 'There was an error.';
            }
        ?>

???

Comment: @CodyM — You need to make the output of the **checked attribute** conditional on the checkbox being checked. You're still making the output of **the whole input element** conditional on that. You also need to give the checkbox the same name!

Answer (score -2):

You need a place to hod the selection such as data source (SQL database), session or cookie can do this. SQL is if you want the infomation to be seved for later use on user base. If you're looking for a temporary solution like a filter function; I recomend use of session. So here goes my version. :)

```html
<?php
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_MOTHOD"] == "POST) {
  if(!empty($_POST["person1"])){
    $_SESSION["person1"] = $_POST["person1"];
  }
  if(!empty($_POST["person2"])){
    $_SESSION["person2"] = $_POST["person2"];
  }
  if(!empty($_POST["person3"])){
    $_SESSION["person3"] = $_POST["person3"];
  }
  if(!empty($_POST["person4"])){
    $_SESSION["person4"] = $_POST["person4"];
  }
}
?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    <ul>
      <li><input type="checkbox" />Tickets</li>
      <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="person1" checked />Person 1's ticket</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="person2" checked />Person 2's ticket</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="person3" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION[ "person3"]))? "checked": ""; ?> />Person 3's ticket</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="person4" <?php echo (isset($_SESSION[ "person3"]))? "checked": ""; ?> />Person 4's ticket</li>
      </ul>
  </form>
```

My use of session function is not the proper way as it's only used for user validation mainly but it shoud do the trick.

Comment: This should persist data until the browser is closed

Comment: This will need to be able to be viewed by all users.